# Origin of Bajrang Baan

Tags: identification-request, hanuman, stotra

In which scripture Bajrang Baan is mentioned and is there are multiple versions or one version of Bajrang Baan?

One version can be found on [Hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Bhajarang_baan)

Comment: Author is Tulsidas so it might be an independent work

Comment: @Rickross can you let me know in which book of Tulsidas, this stotra is mentioned.

Comment: Sorry I don't know that

Comment: @Rickross ok no worries bro.

Answer (score 2):

The authorship of Bajraṅg Bāṇ is traditionally attributed to Gosvami Tulsidas. It's not contained in any 'book' or 'collection of works'; it's thought of as an independent composition by Tulsidas-jī.

As regards the existence of multiple versions of Bajranga-Bana.

Yes, there's a huge variation in the 'number of verses' & wording sequences across different versions of the Bajraṅg Bāṇ.

As Philip Lutgendorf notes in his '[Hanuman's Tale - The Messages of a Divine Monkey](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780195309225.001.0001/acprof-9780195309225)' -

> The Bajraṅg Bāṇ (Arrow of the iron-limbed [Hanuman]) has a format similar to that of the Cālīsā, beginning and ending with a couplet in dohā meter,
> bracketing a series of caupāīs verses. **But its printed versions show
> a wider range of variations in individual lines** and it appears to be
> coalescing more slowly than its celebrated cousin.<sup>17</sup>
>
> ---
>
> Footnote 17.
>
> One anthology of ritual texts for Hanuman worship warns readers, with regard to the Bajraṅg Bāṇ: ‘‘You don’t get the correct text
> in the market. There are many errors, therefore this correct version
> is being printed. The text has been taken from a very old manuscript’’
> (Shrimali n.d.:117). **In fact, the text provided shows great variation
> from most other printed versions, with fifty-eight caupāīs versus
> the usual thirty-five; the compiler does not identify his source.**
>
> *(page 102)*

So as per Lutgendorf, the number of verses in the different versions of Bajraṅg Bāṇ varies between 35 verses to 58 verses.

The same observation is made by 'the Sanskrit Documents Website' on their [pag](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_otherlang_hindi/bajarangabaaNHindi.html)e on the Bajraṅg Bāṇ:

> sanskritdocuments => Bajraṅg Bāṇ
>
> **There are quite a few variations seen in the print mainly
> due to mixed old-new Hindi and different chaupAI sequences.**